# Running ServiceStack on Mono on OSX

Tags: asp.net-mvc, macos, mono, servicestack

Trying to get ServiceStack working on OSX - currently getting a file not found error on System.Web.Entity.dll

Is there a Nuget I need to pull in or do I need to do what this dude says: http://veereshr.com/DotNet/PortMvc3ToLinux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't directly an issue with ServiceStack. The issue actually stems from old licensing restrictions on Mono by Microsoft.

### MVC3 + Mono 2.10 / Mono 3+

Yes the instructions for copying the files from your windows deployment into your web app's `bin` directory is the Mono prescribed work around, as noted here in the [Mono release notes](http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.10#ASP.NET_MVC3_Support) given that you are targeting MVC3.

> Running Razor, MVC3 and WebPages
>
> To get this stack running, you will need to copy Microsoft's MVC3 libraries into your bin directory:
>
> System.Web.Mvc.dll
> System.Web.Razor.dll
> System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll
> System.Web.WebPages.dll

### MVC4 + Mono 3+

If you are targeting MVC4 then Mono 3.X [now includes ASP.NET WebStack](http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_3.0).

---

### To clarify:

- If you target MVC3 always copy the dlls (even if you are on Mono 3+).
- If you target MVC4 you don't need to copy dlls they are bundled with Mono 3+.

Comment: this is weird then as I am on mono 3.2.5 yet I still get these issues?

Comment: @iwayneo But are you using MVC3 or MVC4? If you have MVC3 it has been supported since Mono 2.10, and is supported in Mono 3+, but you need to copy the dlls. Having Mono 3+ doesn't mean MVC3 is supported without copying dlls. It just means in Mono 3+ you have support for MVC4 without copying dlls.

Comment: i've moved all my code into an mvc project but now I get a stack overflow exception: at System.Attribute.GetHashCode () [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-3.2.5/mcs/class/corlib/System/Attribute.cs:261

Comment: I'm getting errors saying: `Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Entity' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.` Any ideas? I've got Xamarin Studio v5.5 and Mono `Version Information: 3.10.0 ((detached/47db868 Thu Oct 2 22:04:39 EDT 2014); ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319.17020`